# PHP read number of pages of .doc file on Linux

Tags: php, linux, .doc

I'm trying to read number of pages for .doc files specifically, with PHP. Or at least convert the .doc file to .pdf(or.docx), then I read pdf's pages with Xpdf easily.

The problem is that my PHP code runs on external server with installed Linux and apache on it. The server allows me to do `exec()` commands, but when I try to use LibreOffice(or OO)'s converter in headless mode, I always get error `command not found`. Same result with executing `apt-get`, `lowriter` or `sudo` commands.

Comment: Are you using the full path to the executables in your `exec()` calls? It's likely that the user Apache is running as doesn't have the same path you do as a regular user.

Comment: I have these settings in the cpanel: https://postimg.org/image/9bb7gl475/ 
I've added the last path, but no change

Comment: If you're using something hosted like that, are you even sure you have any LibreOffice installed? You're really unlikely to have sudo rights, too.